# Core update of 4.2.3 changes all link to https

Tags: updates, ssl, https

Latest update of wp 4.2.3 applied to my two to three installation automatically. After that my all links starting with https due to that sites are not opening properly

Can anyone know what the changes in 4.2.3 from previous one.

For quick fix I change wp-includes/function.php is_ssl() so that it will return false compulsory.

This question is mark duplicate, But referred question is based on chrome. this question is based on wp. chrome is not redirecting the link to https. proof if you forcefully return false from is_ssl() funtion then site will work fine. So basically some how is_ssl() returning true after the said updates so my question is which factor or cause is forcing is_sll() to return true. I had not changed any thing in core files.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, site wasn't loading with Chrome after the update (I guess Firefox/Safari handles this somehow differently), because of those https asset links.

Are you using WooCommerce by any chance? After updating that I got my site running again,
here is a part of their changelog:

*Fix - Fixed Google Chrome forcing to use SSL. This can cause some issues on websites behind load balancers or reverse proxies. [Read more.](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/ssl-and-https/#websites-behind-load-balancers-or-reverse-proxies)*

Edit: See also this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/195377/chrome-version-44-0-2403-89-m-is-trying-to-force-https).

Comment: I updated the question, My question is not related to chrome